# Alternate Application.Run Winform In Program.cs File

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a project of two Winform and I want to run the application by alternate form. In program.cs file there is:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

That means the Form1 will execute as main form or startup form of application.
Is it possible to change it programmatically by some time limit or days limit?
I mean after two days it will execute Form2  as startup form.
Like below:

```
Application.Run(new Form2());
```

Is it possible?

Comment: you could do this by keeping a track of when the application was opened and in which `Form` (possibly using a text file). Before loading the form, read from the text file and switch the form to load accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, that's no problem:

```
var startDate = ReadStartDateFromFile();
if(DateTime.Now.Subtract(startDate).TotalDays < 2 || startDate == new DateTime())
    Application.Run(new Form1());
else
    Application.Run(new Form2());
```

The method `ReadStartDateFromFile` reads the date of the first start of your program. If it has never been started before, it returns `new DateTime()`.
If you want to use this as a way to implement a shareware mechanism, consider using an obfuscator, otherwise, it is very easy to crack. Additionally, you should encrypt the file, you write the start date to. Additionally, consider a setup, that creates that file with a dummy date. If someone simply deletes the file, you should consider that a security breach and directly show `Form2`.

Thanks to Mark for the great discussion in the comments!

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth, I wants to give days limit like after two days

Comment: @mahesh: Then do something like this: If the programs runs for the first time, save the date somewhere in a text file or so. On subsequent runs, read that textfile substract that date from `DateTime.Now` and you have the difference in days. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Daniel, @Mahesh: if you store something like this in a text file, I would recommend encrypting it in some way; otherwise, a user could just edit the text file and set the date to some point in the future (thus giving them more time).

Comment: @Mark Avenius: I fully agree. Even than it can only stop average people from cracking it, because it's no one-way encryption.

Comment: @Daniel: true, but if you use 128 bit or higher, it's pretty darn close to two-way :-)

Comment: @Mark Avenius: As long as the obfuscator he is using, is doing a good job ;-) Because all info to decrypt and encrypt that file is in the program. BTW: In the current "implementation" it would be enough to simply delete the file... ;-) He would need a setup which creates the file and puts a dummy value in it and consider the scenario when the file is missing as a security breach and stop working...

Comment: @mahesh: The little discussion between Mark and me should show you, that it is not trivial to prevent people from cracking your program.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth, @ Mark Avenius, I appreciate your both way of discussion and it is important to discuss more on some point of security. I welcome both of you.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth, I have no idea about shareware mechanism can you guide me?

Comment: @mahesh: I never released any shareware, so all my input is theoretical and simply based on common sense and my experience. Anyway, I think this is not the scope of the question. If my answer helped you with your question as you formulated it, please kindly accept it. If you want to ask something specific about shareware and protection from cracking, my suggestion is that you create a new question.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth, thanks for guide me. I hereby accept your answer

Answer (score 2):

```
if(someRuleToDetermineIfForm1NeedsToRun)
{
  Application.Run(new Form1());
}
else if(someRuleToDetermineIfForm2NeedsToRun)
{
  Application.Run(new Form2());
}
else // default
{
  Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

Comment: @mahesh, use this approach with a text file which stores the last form used.

Answer (score 1):

Sure; you can do this:

```
if (condition1)
    Application.Run(new Form1());
else
    Application.Run(new Form2());
```

You can set the condition based on arguments passed in, etc.